# Node error when I run npm with laravel breeze

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I have this error when I run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` and I didn't find what is the mess. It's happens in a all fresh Laravel 8 app.

It looks like happen when I use the developement command

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
TypeError: [(...variantsValue),(...extensions)].flat is not a function
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/resolveConfig.js:219:73
    at baseMergeDeep (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_baseMergeDeep.js:42:7)
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_baseMerge.js:27:7
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_createBaseFor.js:17:11
    at baseMerge (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_baseMerge.js:24:3)
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/mergeWith.js:36:3
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_createAssigner.js:30:9
    at apply (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_apply.js:15:25)
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/lodash/_overRest.js:32:12
    at mergeVariantExtensions (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/resolveConfig.js:218:33)
    at resolveVariants (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/resolveConfig.js:235:10)
    at resolveConfig (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/resolveConfig.js:271:15)
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js:77:37
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:52:20
    at LazyResult.run (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:288:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:212:26)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:225:14)
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:217:17
    at runLoaders (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20)
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.catch (/var/www/html/smart_recipe/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js:208:9)
 @ ./resources/css/app.css
```

Comment: Are you running this in the project root directory?

Comment: @Bennett Ye ssure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came across same issue and spent 5 hours on finding solution but could not.
After searching alot, I came across this

> "Tailwind CSS v2.0 no longer supports Node.js 8 or 10. To build your CSS you'll need to ensure you are running Node.js 12.13.0 or higher in both your local and CI environments."

at  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2

So I realized that issue was in my Node version which was 10.x so
I uninstalled Node from my windows machine and downloaded LTS version (14.x).
So consider updating your Node version, it will solve the issue as it did work for me.
There is possibility that old node versions don't have that flat function that Tailwind CSS 2 has implemented and that's throwing error.

Answer (score 2):

I Had the exact same issue after installing Breeze... Unfortunately the npm error message gives no clue of what is really going on !

Thanks to @DaniyalGondal I found out that my node version was raising the error because of tailwind V2 requirements (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2) that comes with Breeze... So I did upgrade my node version using : `sudo n latest` under ubuntu20

Don't forget to restart your terminal after upgrading and check that your node is correctly upgraded using : `node --version`

If the node version is above 12.13.0, now `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` should work fine !

Comment: This will fix the issue but perhaps it would be better to point out the reason why this fixes the problem. Likely OP is not on node version 11.0.0. which is the node version that the array method .flat() was introduced.

Comment: You're abolutly right !! The first functionnal version seems to be 12.13.0 as said in the docs... I Add it to my post right now !